# Why does WebSphere search for a non existing EAR file and fails to publish an Application?

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, ibm-rad

I'm maintaining a legacy Enterprise Application which unfortunately runs on IBM WebSphere Application Server v. 7.0.0.45. The IDE is IBM RAD and the application consists of two projects: the first one is the web module and the second one the EAR container. The latter actually contains the deployment descriptor (application.xml), so no .EAR file is really generated on the file system within the EAR project.

The issue I'm having is that whenever I make any change in the web app and then save the source file, RAD first rebuilds the web app and then tries to re-publish the .EAR file to WAS, but the deployment always fails with the error: "Failed to open C:/Path_to_Application/xxx_w1_MyApplication/MyApplicationEAR/MyApplicationEAR.ear".

```
[28/11/23 11.06.58:301 CET] 0000001c CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=MyApplicationEAR in BLA WebSphere:blaname=MyApplicationEAR failed to start.
[28/11/23 11.06.58:703 CET] 0000001c StartDeployme W   Start failed.  ApplicationManager MBean: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=MYUSERNode03,version=7.0.0.45,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=MYUSERNode03Cell,spec=1.0, operation: startApplication, params: [MyApplicationEAR]
[28/11/23 11.06.58:825 CET] 0000001c AppBinaryProc I   ADMA7021I: Distribution of application MyApplicationEAR completed successfully.
[28/11/23 11.06.58:701 CET] 0000001c FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_5a085a08_23.11.28_11.06.58.3265338834176421115024.txt com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke 679
[28/11/23 11.06.58:812 CET] 0000001c FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_5a085a08_23.11.28_11.06.58.7225642279798212295583.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment 256
[28/11/23 11.06.58:856 CET] 0000001c FileRepositor A   ADMR0009I: Document cells/MYUSERNode03Cell/applications/MyApplicationEAR.ear/deltas/MyApplicationEAR/delta-1701166016643 is created.
[28/11/23 11.06.58:864 CET] 00000005 TreeBuilder   W   ODCF0002E: Exception: IWAE0037E Could not open C:/Path_to_Application/xxx_w1_MyApplication/MyApplicationEAR/MyApplicationEAR.ear.
[28/11/23 11.06.58:871 CET] 0000001c FileRepositor A   ADMR0010I: Document cells/MYUSERNode03Cell/applications/MyApplicationEAR.ear/deployments/MyApplicationEAR/META-INF/ibm-application-runtime.props is modified.
[28/11/23 11.06.58:877 CET] 0000001c FileRepositor A   ADMR0010I: Document cells/MYUSERNode03Cell/applications/MyApplicationEAR.ear/deployments/MyApplicationEAR/deployment.xml is modified.
[28/11/23 11.06.59:141 CET] 00000005 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv03\logs\ffdc\server1_552f552f_23.11.28_11.06.58.8782013313554722235215.txt com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder Removing: /cell/MYUSERNode03Cell/application/MyApplicationEAR<<com.ibm.ws.odc.ODCNodeImpl@1cf21cf2>>
[28/11/23 11.07.14:292 CET] 00000016 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1009I: An attempt is made to start the MyApplicationEAR application.
[28/11/23 11.07.14:533 CET] 00000016 CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=MyApplicationEAR in BLA WebSphere:blaname=MyApplicationEAR.
[28/11/23 11.07.14:560 CET] 00000016 ApplicationMg W   WSVR0100W: An error occurred initializing, MyApplicationEAR
com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Failed to open C:/Path_to_Application/xxx_w1_MyApplication/MyApplicationEAR/MyApplicationEAR.ear
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.initialize(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:580)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.initialize(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:420)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.initializeApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:385)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2073)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:648)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:610)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:384)
    at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
    at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1346)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1239)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:595)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.OpenFailureException: IWAE0037E Could not open C:/Path_to_Application/xxx_w1_MyApplication/MyApplicationEAR/MyApplicationEAR.ear
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.primOpenArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1625)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1204)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:612)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl$MappableContentsArchive.open(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1707)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.initialize(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:577)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: IWAE0036E URI Name: C:/Path_to_Application/xxx_w1_MyApplication/MyApplicationEAR/MyApplicationEAR.ear; File name: C:\Path_to_Application\xxx_w1_MyApplication\MyApplicationEAR\MyApplicationEAR.ear
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.createLoadStrategy(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.primOpenArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1619)
    ... 45 more
```

Both projects were imported from our customer's repository as they are. The application is expected to be successfully redeployed locally, after each change in the source code.

Why is WAS searching for a non existing .EAR file within the project folder and how can I fix this issue?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: enclosing a screenshot of publishing settings
[image: publishing settings]

Comment: Are you importing Eclipse project metadata (.project, .settings dir, etc.) committed to the repo?   Is the C:\Path_to_Application\xxx_w1_MyApplication\MyApplicationEAR\MyApplicationEAR.ear path is the path of your project in your RAD workspace?  Maybe you could share  your publishing settings (run resources on workspace, OR server).

Comment: The file .project comes from the repo, while .settings dir is included into .gitignore.
EDIT: not exactly, the path shown in the console error message is the path of the local git repository for the EAR project, the project within RAD's workspace points to that source folder. I don't understand your last statement, sorry. What publishing settings might be useful and how shall I display them?

Comment: To see the publishing settings double-click on the **Servers** view entry like the upper-righthand side of this:  https://gist.github.com/scottkurz/c0cca3ee5d0e20de125d145274cdd966

Comment: I edited my question, sorry about the different language

Comment: No problem.  So it looks like it's "run server with resources within the workspace".   Are there any related entries in "Problems" or the "Error Log" views?  Is everything compiling/building/validating successfully?

Comment: I see no errors in the "Problems" tab, only a number of warnings. No errors are shown in the log/console either, but the FileNotFoundException

Comment: I know enough to keep asking questions and for you to try things but not enough to simply diagnose the problem.   If you can you should try RAD support.  Since StackOverflow is telling me the comment thread is too long let me point you to our WAS forum if you want to chat more there:   https://community.ibm.com/community/user/wasdevops/communities/community-home/digestviewer?communitykey=5c4ba155-561a-4794-9883-bb0c6164e14e